# Max contiguous slice in Ruby

Tags: algorithm, ruby, array, dynamic-programming

I need to compute the max contiguous slice in an array. I wrote this function, but I am not sure if it is correct or I am missing edge cases. I ran several cases.

```
def max_slice(a)
  max_start,max_end = 0,0
  largest_sum = 0
  curr_start,curr_end = 0,0
  curr_sum = 0
  for i in 0..a.length-1 
    if (curr_sum + a[i]  < 0 ) then
      curr_start = i+1
      curr_sum = 0
    elsif (curr_sum + a[i] > curr_sum) then  
      curr_sum = curr_sum + a[i]
      curr_end = i
      if (curr_sum > largest_sum) then
        max_start, max_end = curr_start,curr_end
        largest_sum = curr_sum
      end 
    end
  end
  a[max_start..max_end]
end


p max_slice([-3,39,2,-1,65]) #> [39, 2, -1, 65]
p max_slice([12,-3,39,2,-1,65]) #> [12, -3, 39, 2, -1, 65]
p max_slice([]) #> []
p max_slice([2,3]) #> [2, 3]
p max_slice([-2,3]) #> [3]
p max_slice([-2]) #> [-2]
p max_slice([12,-3,39,2,-1,102]) #> [12, -3, 39, 2, -1, 102]
p max_slice([-5,-3,39,2,-39,65]) #> [39, 2, -39, 65]
p max_slice([-5,5,39,2,-60,65]) #> [65]
p max_slice([-5,35,39,2,-60,65]) #> [35, 39, 2, -60, 65]
p max_slice([-5,35,39,2,-160,65]) #> [35, 39, 2]
```

Comment: I'm voting to put this on hold until you've properly tested the code. If you're unsure it's correct, then the code isn't ready to be reviewed.

Comment: @RubberDuck I would leave it open as "works to the best of OP's knowledge". Sometimes you're pretty sure it works, know there *might* be some missing edge cases, but can't find any problematic one. Well all know that there can't always be a full covergae in the testsuite.

Comment: @Morwenn this sounds very unsure to me. I agree with Ducky here.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is Kadane's algorithm. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm) presents an implementation in Python which should not be hard to rewrite in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a method that takes the array as a parameter, you may want to take advantage of [Ruby Open Classes](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_open_classes.html) and add the method to the `Array` class so that it can operate on itself:

```ruby
Class Array
    def max_slice
      max_start,max_end = 0,0
      largest_sum = 0
      curr_start,curr_end = 0,0
      curr_sum = 0
      for i in 0..self.length-1 
        if (curr_sum + self[i]  < 0 ) then
          curr_start = i+1
          curr_sum = 0
        elsif (curr_sum + self[i] > curr_sum) then  
          curr_sum = curr_sum + self[i]
          curr_end = i
          if (curr_sum > largest_sum) then
            max_start, max_end = curr_start,curr_end
            largest_sum = curr_sum
          end 
        end
      end
      self[max_start..max_end]
    end
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
p [-3,39,2,-1,65].max_slice #> [39, 2, -1, 65]
```

or

```
arr = [-5,5,39,2,-60,65]
p arr.max_slice #> [65]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modularize the code:

```
class Array
  def contiguos_slices
    # Exercise for the reader (or you may find an implementation at StackOverlow)
  end

  def sum
    self.inject(0, :+)
  end

end

p [1,2,-3,4].contiguos_slices.max_by(&:sum)
```